# How can I get input of first class into the second class in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I took the username as an input in the first class along with the pin and destroyed the first window while the second window pops up. I need the username input from the first class to access and update the dictionary. How can I get the input from the first class to be used in the second class?

I tried making self.log and self.pin global variables but it did turn in my favor.

```
class ATMLogin(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, bg=w, **kwargs)

        # SETTING UP WINDOW
        master.title('ATM')
        master.config(bg=w)
        master.geometry('250x340')
        master.resizable(False, False)

        # VARIABLES
        self.log = tk.StringVar()
        self.pin = tk.IntVar()
        self.pin.set('')

        # HEADINGS
        self.head = tk.Label(self, text=' WELCOME TO THE ATM ', justify='center', bg=w, font='Courier 13')
        self.head.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=6)

        self.log_head = tk.Label(self, text=f"{11 * '-'} LOGIN {11 * '-'}", justify='center', bg=w, font='Courier 10')
        self.log_head.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=6)

        self.sig_head = tk.Label(self, text=f"{11 * '-'} SIGNUP {11 * '-'}", justify='center', bg=w, font='Courier 10')
        self.sig_head.grid(row=6, column=0, pady=6)

        # LOGIN SECTION
        self.log_name = tk.Label(self, text='Acc Name', bg=w, font='Courier 9')
        self.log_name.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.log_box1 = tk.Entry(self, bg=lg, textvariable=self.log, width=22)
        self.log_box1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='e', padx=2)

        self.log_pin = tk.Label(self, text='Acc Pin', bg=w, font='Courier 9')
        self.log_pin.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.log_box2 = tk.Entry(self, bg=lg, textvariable=self.pin, show='*', width=22)
        self.log_box2.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='e', padx=2)

class ATMAction(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs, ):
        super().__init__(master, bg=w, **kwargs)

        # SETTING UP WINDOW
        master.title('ATM')
        master.config(bg=w)
        master.geometry('250x340')
        master.resizable(False, False)

        # VARIABLES

        # MAIN GUI
        self.head = tk.Label(self, text=f'WELCOME', justify='center', bg=w, font='Courier 13')
        self.head.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=6)
```

If I put self.log and self.pin as global variables I get an `Attribute Error:
NoneType ......... '_root'`

Comment: Try changing this: `class ATMAction(tk.Frame):` to `class ATMAction(ATMLogin):`. `ATMAction` should inherit the methods of `ATMLogin`

Comment: [Edit] your question and show how do you `instantiate` both `class`es.

Comment: @ColeRobertson It does inherit the method but the first window reopens itself

Comment: Check the complete code from here and please help me use variables from one class to another
git: https://github.com/Ammaros/ATM-Sim-Prob-1

Comment: @AmmarKashif, no, right now they both inherit from `tk.Frame`, which means the methods from one won't be passed to the other.

Comment: @ColeRobertson so what do I do? I cannot inherit the contents from the first window using your method

Comment: Have you read about `class` [inheritance](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php)? It certainly is possible to do what your trying to do, and you should definitely need them to inherit sequentially, as I've suggested. But @stovfl is probably correct. It may have something to do with how you're instantiating your `class` objects. Perhaps you should take his suggestion and edit your post.